# How to read parameters from request in django

Tags: python, django

I need to read some parameters being passed in and perform some action in django. How can I do that.

```
url = 172.15.20.116/request
```

and server is requesting with below parameters

```
url = 172.15.20.116/request/1289/
```

here 1289 is parameter. How to parse it?

Comment: go through http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03.html

Comment: @Nishant The Django Book is **extremely** outdated. I wouldn't recommend it to anyone. Besides, the official docs explain it perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To so this you need to capture this in the urls.

You will need to look into the [django url dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/) this page has pretty much everything you need to get started. Take your time, learn and then implement.

Maybe something like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^request/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'appname.views.my_request_view'),
]
```

views.py

```
def my_request_view(request, id):
    ... # logic goes here
```